# intent on onitem click doesnt work

Tags: android, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

```
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor c = (Cursor)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            call = c.getString(0);
            Intent i = new Intent(null, Ldetail.class);
            i.putExtra("id",call);
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean?

Comment: Instead of null use context or activityname.this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead null use getapplicationcontext()..

Answer (score 3):

Change this line.

```
Intent i = new Intent(null, Ldetail.class);
```

Instead of null use context or activityname.this  . You must have to pass context or activity name .

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourCurrentActivityName.this, Ldetail.class);
```

**Or**

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Ldetail.class);
```

and Declare **Ldetail** activity in android manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

```
  usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

Here you have used View of Adapter View, which is the parent class of your Custom Adapter. that's why it is not working. Instead you should have used the View of Custom Adapter.

getView() function here helps you to convert the View of Parent Adpater View to the Custom Adapter View.

So you use either of the two options,

```
usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new CustomAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

or

```
usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you passing null instead of context?
 
add your context in the intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(yourclassname.this, Ldetail.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(null, Ldetail.class);
        i.putExtra("id",call);
        startActivity(i);
```

You must have to pass context or activity.

```
     Intent i = new Intent(this, Ldetail.class);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Ldetail.class);
```

Comment: i have tried Intent i = new Intent(this, Ldetail.class);
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Ldetail.class);
 but though i m getting runtime error

Comment: show me your error first

Comment: how can i send a screen shot of log cat????

Comment: first edit your whole code.

Comment: plz give me ur mail id.....

Comment: ohk plzz edit on this bcz email ids are blocked in my office